# When are we allowed to cancel $a$ in an equation in a ring?

Tags: ring-theory

> Given three elements $a,b,c$ in a ring $R$. When are we allowed to cancel $a$ from the equation $ab=ac$?

My answer was when there is an element $a'$ which is the element $a$ raised to power $(-1)$, such that $a.a'=e_R$. Am I wrong?

Comment: Exactly when $a$ is not a (left) zero divisor. Your condition is sufficient but not necessary as you can check with $\mathbb{Z}$ and $a=2$.

Comment: Usually $a^{-1}$ is not a defined function for a ring (unlike a field)

Comment: Okay, thank you but this means that my answer is not wrong, just we have to be sure that the ring has an element $e_r$?

Comment: @Jut3 I guess that when you talk about the element $e_r$ you are referring to the multiplicative identity element ? You should not ask whether the ring has this element or no, because by definition it does. Your answer is not correct because, as Quimey pointed out, the equation $ab=ac$ (in a ring) can imply that $b=c$ even if $a$ has not a multiplicative inverse. Just rewrite $ab=ac$ as $a(b-c)=0$, and look for the definition of a left zero divisor.

Comment: @Amelia To be fair, some texts don't include the existence of a multiplicative unit in the definition of a ring (and so consider a separate notion of "unital ring"). Of course that doesn't affect your main point.

Comment: @NoahSchweber ahh you are right ! I forgot about it !

Comment: True, finite order elements are invertible so cancellable, but that sufficient condition is not necessary for cancellability. An equivalent condition is that $a$ is not a zero-divisor, i.e. $\,ax = 0\Rightarrow x = 0\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is related to the concept of *zero-divisors*. Given a ring $R$ a left zero-divisor is an element $a\in R$ such that there is some $b\ne0$ with $ab=0$ ($a$ divides $0$ from the left). If $a\in R$ is *not* a left zero-divisor then $ab=ac\iff a(b-c)=0$ implies that $b-c=0$. This is the most general condition under which cancellation of $a$ will work.

However, there are special cases for which cancellation will work as well. For example if $R$ has an identity element $1$ and $a$ is a right unit, that is there is some $a'\in R$ such that $a'a=1$, as in this case

$$ab=ac\implies b=(a'a)b=(a'a)c=c$$

using associativity. This is due to the fact that right units are never left zero-divisors (which is proved similarily). If we assume $R$ to be commutative (and non-trivial) we get the (slightly) easier to state fact that units are never zero-divisors.

However, $a$ has not to be a unit in order to not be a zero-divisor as the ring $R=\mathbb Z$ shows. This ring does not contain any non-zero zero-divisors at all (such rings are called *integral domains*) and hence the cancellation law always applies. Notably also for *non*-units such as $2\in\mathbb Z$ (as mentioned by *Quimey* it the comments).

Comment: Woooow! Amazing answer to my question, Thank you a lot.

Comment: @Jut3 To be fair: A lot of it was already discussed in the comments but glad to help! :D Consider accepting the answer (the little check box below the votes) if you've no further questions.